# A general rule which applies to different types of bread

Tags: baking, bread

As someone who is not new to baking different types of breads, I would like to conclude from different recipes that regardless of what the directions is about you can add dry ingredients together and whisk, do the same thing about wet ingredients and then mix them all together. Is it right or it depends on the bread you are baking?

Comment: @Jefromi: Actually I haven't baked any quick breads other than tortilla (if it's called so). I am talking about yeast breads like [this one, for example](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/honey-white-bread-recipe.html)

Comment: Organic chemistry takes time. So time should be taken into account in each stage of processing. Unless you are baking bricks, and even that takes time.

Comment: @Optionparty: True fact. But how does it relate to my question?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. It is possible to make bread that way, but it's rather rare.

If you are using any kind of preferment, even a 10 minute sponge, you are likely to add dry ingredients to it. Then you add this mixture of dry+wet to the rest, and the order for "the rest" can vary.

Also, if you have any enrichments, they are usually added after the flour has been kneaded with the main liquid, especially if you are using fats.

Whisking can also be skipped in many cases, sometimes to spare time, sometimes because you don't start with a ratio of water to flour and prewhisking the correct amount of yeast to 10 times the flour you need (well method) will lead to 1/10 of the needed yeast in the end product.

Then there are complicated recipes where you e.g. start out with half your water frozen to slush, or are using very large amounts of preferment so that 1/2 of your ingredients is sourdough which is neither liquid nor dry, etc.

There is indeed a basic process common to all bread baking, but it is not on the level of mixing order, it is about the rhythm of kneading and proofing. All mixing, no matter how many stages it has, is a single step in it, typically the second one.